# why is the page id is a unrelated number?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i just started learning MySQL with Php. and in my tutorial lessons i have created one database which has two tables, "subjects" and "pages". these are relational databases. the primary key of "subject" is called from pages table through a variable called subject_id in MySQL. eventually they are supposed to be a navigation menu where the "subject" is category and "pages" is the subcategory.
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nod4T.png)

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KhRY.png)

Now in my Php code i have:

```
<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
        <ul>

            <?php $subject_set = find_all_subjects(); ?>
            <?php while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)){ ?>

            <li><a href="manage_content.php?subject= <?php echo urlencode($subject["id"]);?>"><?php echo $subject["menu_name"];?></a>
            <?php $page_set = find_pages_for_subjects($subject["id"]); ?>
                <ul>        
                    <?php while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)){ ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="manage_content.php?page= <?php echo urlencode($page["id"]);?>"><?php echo $page["menu_name"];?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php mysqli_free_result($page_set);?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php mysqli_free_result($subject_set);?>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

and in my function.php i have:

```
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set){
    if (!$result_set){
        die("DB Query Failed");
    }
}

function find_all_subjects(){
    global $connection;
    $query = "select * ";
    $query .= "from subjects ";
    $query .= "where visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "order by position asc";
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    return $subject_set;

}

function find_pages_for_subjects($subject_id){
        global $connection; 
        $query = "select * ";
        $query .= "from pages ";
        $query .= "where visible = 1 ";
        // an aditional line to relate pages to the subject, subject_id is what rlate two tables together
        // dont forget space between lines
        $query .= "AND subject_id = {$subject_id} ";
        $query .= "order by position asc";
        $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        // the result captured can not be used twice for two different queries 
        // so result varibale should have unique names 
        confirm_query($page_set);
        return $page_set;
}
?>
```

simple queries, now the output should be something like this:

the problem is when i click on the pages i am supposed to get the subject id which is probably up to 3 or 4 in the url, but instead i am getting:

localhost:8888/CMS/public/manage_content(dot)php?page=%201

" (dot) is . "

where that 201 come from?? how can i set it back to original number which is 1 in case of first page for example? please if you need more info ask i can provide my whole files just to find out where this come from.

thank you

Comment: Remove space after '=' in ?page= <?php echo urlencode

Comment: the `%20` is the url encoded value of a space ` ` so it is really `?page= 1`

Comment: thank you Andrej Ludinovskov and RamRaider, that little space was the problem now i am getting the url i want with http://localhost:8888/CMS/public/manage_content(dot)php?page=1 but in the tutorial the page doesnt change only the url changes but the page stays the same, mine goes to "Not Found" page. do you have any idea why?

Comment: Dot is real . I just wrote that way to scape the some restriction the actual link doesnt have dot its just .

Answer (score 1):

As an aside - and ignoring (just for a moment) the advantages of prepared statements with bound parameters, I find this kind of thing easier to read...

```
function find_pages_for_subjects($subject_id){
        global $connection; 
        $query = "
        SELECT * 
          FROM pages 
         WHERE visible = 1 
           AND subject_id = {$subject_id} 
         ORDER 
            BY position ASC;
        ";
```

Comment: And easy to convert to a statement that can be prepared.

Comment: Good point and thank Ryan Vincent. i keep that in mind, there is no need to concatenate when just can have the whole query in one variable.